# Regex syntax matching against a certificate

Tags: regex

I'm working on authentication on a cisco appliance that uses regex to pull the correct username from a certificate.

I have a little detail that I can't figure out in the format combinations.

I have got the right regex combination to pull the correct format from my certificate as: `/Subject:.*CN=\w+\.\w+\.(?<userPrincipalName>(\d+))/m`

The problem arises when my coworker attempts to use it to pull his username it gives me a no match

The problem I have is that the usernames are in `FIRSTNAME.MIDDLENAME.LASTNAME.123456789@email` format on the certificates

The only thing I need to pull from that certificate is the `123456789@email`

so for example my certificate pulls the CommonName as: `Mike.Smith.123456789@email`

the regex I applied : `/Subject:.*CN=\w+\.\w+\.(?<userPrincipalName>(\d+))/m`

gives me `123456789@email` which is exactly what I need

the problem is when my co worker who has a middle name
: `John.Frank.Jones.123456789@email`

it won't pull correctly and gives me a *No Match*

If I change the regex to `/Subject:.*CN=\w+\.\w+\.\w+\.(?<userPrincipalName>(\d+))/m`

it will pull the correct name since it gets rid of all three names and only leaves the `123456789@email`

the issues is that now my cert does not pull correctly since it discards everything including the number

Is there a regex combination that will only pull a `123456789@email` and discard anything on the left?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/KmgGwS/1

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
Subject:.*CN=(?:\w+\.)+(?<userPrincipalName>\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KmgGwS/1)

The main point is the `(?:\w+\.)+` part that matches 1 or more sequences of one or more word chars followed with a `.`  symbol.

**Pattern details**:

- `Subject:`  - a literal substring
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `CN=` - a literal substring
- `(?:\w+\.)+` - 1 or more sequences of one or more word chars followed with a `.`  symbol
- `(?<userPrincipalName>\d+)` - a "userPrincipalName" group that matches and captures 1 or more digits.

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense. Thanks for the solid answer & explanation, you are much appreciated sir